# Qual é a diferença semântica entre <em> e <strong>? Eles substituem <i> e <b>?

Tags: html, html5, semântica

Dizem que o elemento `<em>` deve ser usado para ênfase, e o `<strong>` para ênfases ainda mais intensas. Isso parece bastante confuso. Quando e por que usar cada um deles? E `<i>` e `<b>`, ainda devem ser usados em alguma situação? Eles foram substituídos por `<em>` e `<strong>`?

Comment: use <'i'> para itálico e <'b'> para negrito, pronto, acabou! :)

Comment: Isso não é recomendado nem responde ao que eu perguntei!

Comment: pergunto-me, porquê complicar termos simples? Termos simples, como o nome sugere, responde-se com simples argumentos, agora, complicar o simples, é simplesmente perder tempo.. pense!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As tags `<i>`, `<em>`, `<b>` e `<strong>` acabam sendo confundidas ou utilizadas erroneamente pelo fato de, na maioria das vezes, terem o mesmo tipo de renderização no browser (as duas primeiras tendo o texto em itálico, e as duas últimas sendo em negrito). Mas seus significados diferem, sendo que:

> - **`<i>` = Utilizado para designar um texto de destaque diferenciado, como em termos especiais ou uso em taxonomia.**

- Exemplo: `A arvore, de nome em latin <i>Araucária brasiliensis</i>`
- Output.: A árvore, de nome em latin *Araucária brasiliensis*

> - **`<em>` =  Utilizado para dar ênfase em uma palavra (ou frase) que você falaria com entonação diferenciada do resto do texto e que mudaria seu significado.**

- Exemplo: `E ela jura que <em>não</em> sabe, não é mesmo?!`
- Ouput: E ela jura que *não* sabe, não é mesmo?!

> - **`<b>` = Direcionado a textos que necessitem ter destaque, mas sem conotação ou explicação explícita.**

- Exemplo: `O e-mail dela é <b>fulana@email.com</b>`
- Output: O e-mail dela é **fulana@email.com**

> - **`<strong>` = Utilizado para dar ênfase a uma palavra ou frase de alta importância.**

- Exemplo: `Pessoal, eu realmente preciso destes relatórios <strong>para amanhã sem falta</strong>!`
- Output: Pessoal, eu realmente preciso destes relatórios **para amanhã sem falta**!

As tags `<i>` e `<b>` tinham muita utilidade no início da era web, quando era comum que tags HTML servissem para estilizar visualmente o conteúdo de uma página.

Com a evolução da internet e dos navegadores, e com a criação da linguagem CSS, é ideal que o conteúdo seja estilizado via propriedades CSS, e não via tags (ou atributos) HTML, o que retira a necessidade de utilizar as tags acima para fins visuais e as torna úteis apenas para uso semântico e de usabilidade.

---

<sup>Referências:</sup>

<sup>http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element</sup>
<sup>http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element</sup>
<sup>http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element</sup>
<sup>http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element</sup>
<sup>http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/</sup>
<sup>http://engineeredweb.com/blog/2013/html5-semantic-diff-bold-strong/</sup>

Comment: Excelente explicação e referências, obrigado! Mas continuo achando um pouco vaga a diferença do em para o strong. Se você usa uma entonação diferente, muitas vezes é porque a coisa é importante, não? Eu entendo a diferença nos exemplos dados, mas na hora de aplicar a qualquer conteúdo não sei se estará tão claro.

Comment: +1 pelas referências.

Comment: @bfavaretto, Vejo o `<em>` como uma forma de mostrar que você utilizou uma entonação diferente no sentido de termos mais súbitos, por exemplo para definir um trecho irônico em sua frase. No caso do `<strong>` seria algo de extrema importância e destaque.

Comment: Entendi. Vou manter isso em mente na próxima vez que precisar deles na prática, e ver se dá certo :)

Answer (score 19):

Ambas são válidas e parece que cada vez mais clara a diferença entre elas. Se bem que sirvam aproximadamente o mesmo objetivo, na descrição da W3C deste mês as diferenças são claras para `<b>` e `<strong>`:

> The strong element represents strong importance, seriousness, or urgency for its contents.

Ou seja, o [elemento `<strong>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element) deve ser usado para descrever/representar "forte importância", "seriedade" ou "urgência" no seu conteudo.

No mesmo documento o [elemento `<b>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element) é descrito como pedaço de texto onde se pretende chamar a atênção por razões práticas sem juntar significado de importância e sem significar alteração de "tom de voz" ou comportamento.

No original:

> The b element represents a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood, such as key words in a document abstract, product names in a review, actionable words in interactive text-driven software, or an article lede.

Os casos do [`<i>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element) e [`<em>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element) são menos claros. Neste caso diz a autoridade o elemento `<i>` deve ser usado em termos técnicos, onde o texto é de um tipo diferente como em nomes de taxonomia ou termos técnicos. O elemento `<em>` é o mais ambiguo, porém uma diferença importante é que podem ser usados "aninhados" <sup>em Inglês "nested"</sup>. Ou seja se usarmos `<em>Hoje está um <em>lindo</em> dia, certo?</em>` a palavra **lindo** vai ter um nivel de acento diferente do resto da frase.

Imagino que estas diferênças mais ou menos subtís venham a ser importantes no futuro em programas que interpretam HTML. Aliás eles já o são para por exemplo pessoas invisuais poderem ter informação extra sobre esse texto.

Comment: Interessante esse uso aninhado, mas nunca vi ninguém usar!

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, eu também não, mas dá ideia que está a W3C está a abrir portas para tal uso.

Comment: Grande pergunta, @bfavaretto, direto pras paradas de sucesso! É curioso que tipo o [Font Awesome pegou o `<i>` pra renderizar os ícones](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/), o que acha disso Sergio?

Comment: @brasofilo curioso. Acho estranho (e errado) esse uso uma vez que a ideia não é diferenciar texto mas sim introduzir um icon numa tag com conteudo vazio. Pergunto-me porque terão tomado essa linha...

Comment: Eu acho que escolheram por causa do "i" de "ícone". Sério mesmo.

Comment: Pobre `<i>`! Sequestraram a criança... Vai sobrar pro `<b>` daqui a pouco :)

Comment: @brasofilo, e Sergio acho que a questão do [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) utilizar o elemento `<i>` foi um erro, veja que esse mesmo erro foi cometido pelo [bootstrap na versão anterior 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons), e agora na [versão 3.0](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) já alteração para o elemento `<span>`, que é um elemento sem fins semânticos (até onde sei), pois era uma abordagem não semântico utilizar o `<i>`, e acredito que o Font Awesome tomará uma decisão similar em versões futuras.

Comment: @brasofilo A tag `<i/>` foi escolhida porque a FontAwesome foi preparada para uso com o Bootstrap apesar de ser compatível com qualquer outra framework. Na altura, o Bootstrap fazia uso do `<i/>` para representar um icon, algo que foi descontinuado e devidamente aprimorado para uma `<span/>`. No fundo, `<i/>` é mais curto que `<span/>` e assume-se que a escolha partir por uma markup com menos "peso".

Comment: Pois é, eu também me perguntava porque o Font Awesome usa o <i> para os ícones, pois isso é completamente errado. O <span> realmente não tem nenhum valor semântico.

Answer (score 2):

`<em>`: Serve para dar uma ênfase em determinado texto, como se você estivesse aumentando a entonação da sua voz para deixar aquela palavra destacada e visível.

**Ex.:**

```
<p>
    <em> Faça sua lição! </em>
</p>
```

`<strong>`: Ele dá importância/seriedade/urgência a determinado texto. A sua renderização atualmente é feita em negrito, mas antigamente o sublinhado era aplicado. Apenas o use caso o texto em questão seja **muito importante** para o usuário.

**Ex.:**

```
<p>
    <strong>Para agora</strong> com isso.
</p>
```

Outra função do `<strong>` é dar uma maior hierarquia/destaque a uma determinada palavra.

**Ex.:**

```
<h1> Capítulo 1 - <strong>A Crise</strong> </h1>
```

Você pode aninhar um `<strong>` dentro de um `<strong>` ou um `<em>` dentro de um `<strong>`... para dar ainda mais ênfase/importância ao texto em questão, apenas não exagere no aninhamento (use no máximo 3 níveis e olhe lá).

**Esses carinhas acima servem para substituir o `<b>` e o `<i>`?**
Não! Cada tag tem ser valor semântico e sua utilidade. Por exemplo, vamos dar uma olhada no `<i>`

`<i>`: Ele é usado em textos ideomáticos, tipo quando você quer escrever um provérbio chinês, ou uma expressão em inglês... Você usa `<i>`, apenas não se esqueça de utilizar o atributo `lang` junto se possível.

**EX.:**

```
<p>
    <i class="phrase" lang="en-us"> You are making up excuses </i> é uma frase que significa: você está criando desculpas.
</p>
```

Outro caso é quando você quer citar um nome taxonômico.

**Ex.:**

```
<p>
    O <i class="taxonomy"> Homo Sapiens </i> é o ser humano.
</p>
```

**Psiu**: já que o `<i>` tem baixo valor semântico, coloque uma classe nele para ajudar a quem for ler o código e também para aumentar o SEO.

Tem mais casos de uso também:
Nomes de embarcações, transliterações, sonhos, pensamentos, termos técnicos... Enfim, dá pra perceber que o `<i>` tem bem mais utilidades do que o `<em>`, mas isso não quer dizer que o `<i>` substitui o `<em>`. Cada elemento é especial.

**Mas e o `<b>` e o `<strong>`?**
É a mesma coisa:

`<b>`: Ele serve para propósitos materiais, tipo quando você quer dar uma pequena importância a um elemento, mas nada muito considerável. Ele serve mesmo para marcar palavras-chave de um documento.

**EX.:**

```
<p>
    O <b>HTML</b> é uma <b>linguagem de marcação</b> muito antiga. Ela foi criada por <b>Tim Bernes-Lee</b>
</p>
```

**Novamente**: nenhuma tag substitui a outra, ambas têm seus casos de uso.

Vale ressaltar também que você pode utilizar uma folha de estilo para sobrescrever os estilos dos elementos acima, isso é normal e correto.