# Quantidade de vezes que devo utilizar o elemento strong para destacar uma palavra como importante?

Tags: html, seo

Estou estudando HTML fiquei com a seguinte dúvida:

```
<h2>Elemento <strong>div</strong></h2>
O elemento <strong>div</strong> também define uma sessão genérica de uma página, ou seja, pode representar qualquer tipo de conteúdo. O elemento <strong>section</strong> difere do elemento <strong>div</strong> pois ele tem uma semantica envolvida, o conteúdo faz sentido estar naquele ponto, no entanto o elemento <strong>div</strong> permite que não tenhamos nenhuma relação com o conteúdo...<br>
É muito usado para fazer formatação de página, para poder alterar o conteúdo com javascript, então <strong>div</strong> é uma sessão sem uma semântica associada.
```

No trecho acima:

1. Destaquei a palavra "div" usando o elemento `strong` no meu título em `h2`.
2. Na descrição a respeito do elemento "div" voltei a destacar a mesma informação com o `strong` novamente por 3 vezes.

Minha dúvida é se isso faz sentido para os buscadores como Google ou Bing e se isso impacta em algo por eu ter este número de destaques maior ou somente o destaque da palavra "div" no título bastaria.

Answer (score 7):

Vou deixar minha consideração. Sobre o que é Bold `<b>` e `<strong>` vc pode ler aqui [Qual é a diferença semântica entre <em> e <strong>? Eles substituem <i> e <b>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32289/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-sem%C3%A2ntica-entre-em-e-strong-eles-substituem-i-e-b) e **isso tem muito mais a ver com semântica e acessibilidade do que com SEO.** Essas tag são para auxiliar os leitores de tela, e apesar de mudar o aspecto visual do elemento, o que está em jogo é o valor semântico do conteúdo, e não se o elemento aparenta estar em negrito ou não.

Como já é amplamente discutido ninguém consegue saber ao certo como o crawler do Google funciona, essa é uma pergunta de 1 milhão de dólares e quem descobrir está rico. O que vc pode faze são `testes A/B` e verificar a indexação. Um teste bem básico seria colocar sua palavra chave entre tag `<strong>` e ver se seu rankeamento melhor nos próximos dias. Não faça muitas mudanças de uma vez, pois vc não vai conseguir identificar o que de fato aumento o rankeamento ou não. Sugiro que leia esses artigos https://resultadosdigitais.com.br/blog/teste-ab-google-analytics/ e https://rockcontent.com/blog/seo-split-testing/

Outra coisa, pense na hierarquia de importância das coisas. Quando tudo parece ser muito importante, nada é importante, pois para o usuário tudo parece ter a mesma importância... Parece bobo, mas um texto com negrito de mais acaba homogenizando e tirando a relevância do que realmente é importante, e o Google pode levar isso em consideração.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vc acha que o Google vai classificar um conteúdo tratado dessa forma? ;)

Essas dicas para a **Palavra Chave** talvez façam mais sentido do que encher seu texto de `<strong>`s

- Palavra Chave no Início do título
- Palavra Chave na Meta Descrição
- Quanto mais cedo aparece no texto melhor (não várias vezes)
- 2-3 variações diferentes de palavras-chave em texto
- H1 A palavra-chave exata
- Variação de palavras-chave H2
- Nos seus URLs
- No texto âncora do link interno
- No `ALT` das imagens caso tenha imagens

*Fonte:* https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/118689/83593

Comment: "Quando tudo parece ser muito importante, nada é importante". Falo tudo.

Answer (score 4):

Esse é um tema controverso e baseado em opiniões.

Não dá para afirmar com precisão, a quantidade de vezes que você pode ou não usar esse recurso. O fato é que ele tem sua utilidade, e nos dias atuais os algorítimos de ranqueamento dos buscadores estão muito mais inteligentes e existem **N** variáveis que somadas vão dar um resultado final positivo ou negativo.

Segundo a [Mozzila](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong#Notas_de_uso) a semântica da tag implica em:

> O elemento  é utilizado em conteúdos que são de "grande importância", incluindo coisas de urgentes (como alertas). Podem ser sentenças que são de grande importância para toda a página, ou, você pode meramente tentar pontuar que algumas palavras são de grande importância, comparado ao conteúdo próximo.

Talvez um teste que possa funcionar para saber se faz sentido, é substituir os valores das tags por algo como: *Atenção!*. Mas no final da conta é muito subjetivo afirmar.

Uma coisa que já é conhecida é que: "*O Google detesta quando descobre que os sites estão tentando truques técnicos, em vez de fazer algo que também beneficia os usuários...*"

[Esta pergunta](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118687/will-it-help-seo-to-use-strong-tags-just-around-a-keyword-while-making-a-large) possui mais algumas referências as quais você pode se basear e tomar suas próprias conclusões.

Answer (score 4):

Para efeitos de SEO, a resposta é 0.

Você não deve aplicar `<b>`, `<strong>` ou qualquer tipo de destaque em qualquer palavra do texto pensando apenas em SEO.

Existem algumas variáveis sabidamente observadas pelo Google para avaliar a relevância de uma página, mas a quantidade de vezes que a palavra chave está negritada no texto é certamente **irrelevante**.

Isso não funciona, e eventualmente, dependendo da situação, imagino que até possa ser identificada como uma [`ação manual`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175?hl=pt-BR) pelo buscador.

O que funciona é ser útil ao usuário, é fornecer uma boa experiência. Então, para decidir quando você deve destacar as palavras chave no texto, você deve pensar na experiência do usuário; apenas nisso.

O negrito por exemplo deve sempre ser utilizado como se fosse em um texto offline, com a finalidade de realmente destacar uma palavra, frase ou expressão que seja importante dentro do texto.

Acho que uma boa dica é pensar mais amplamente, na [escaneabilidade do texto](https://rockcontent.com/blog/escaneabilidade/), e utilizar os destaques dentro dos pontos de foco da leitura em F, o que proporcionará que o usuário permaneça **mais tempo na página**, e que **encontre o que procura com facilidade**.

Imagem do padrão de leitura em F:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas perceba que favorecer a escaneabilidade não é pensando no rankeamento, e sim em melhorar **a experiência de  leitura do usuário**, o que irá afetar diversas métricas importantes, como o tempo de permanência na página, a taxa de rejeição...

Pense o seguinte: se o usuário entra na sua página e sai rapidamente  - assustado com tanto negrito p.ex. rsrs - e volta ao Google para pesquisar novamente sobre a mesma palavra chave que o fez chegar na sua página, então é claro que **o google sabe que você não resolveu o problema dele**, e isso é ruim.

Ao contrário, se ele para de buscar pela palavra chave, e permaneceu certo tempo na sua página, isso indica que sua página resolveu o problema dele, e isso é bom. Se o negrito ajudar nisso, legal, caso contrário, não use.

P.S: Uma boa maneira de 'saber' o que o Google 'pensa' da sua página é utilizar o https://web.dev, ferramenta do Google que serve para avaliar não apenas SEO, mas tbm performance, acessibilidade e boas práticas.

Comment: Eu achava que o F pattern era natural do usuário, e não algo que deveria ser "favorecido" ou fomentado, achava que ele apenas mostrava que ao longo do texto o usuário ia perdendo o interesse e deixando de ler até o final... Vc tem algum link sobre isso pra recomendar?

Comment: O ponto não é favorecer ou fomentar a leitura em F, é utilizar os pontos de foco da leitura em F para incluir informações valiosas, e fazer com que o usuário continue lendo. Na resposta tem um link de referência em `escaneabilidade do texto`.

Comment: Faz sentido, Ler-lhe-ei-lo ;D

Comment: Mas vc tem razão, relendo agora vi que tinha falado em 'favorecer' a leitura em F mesmo, quando o correto seria dizer que é bom utilizar os destaques **dentro dos pontos** de foco da leitura em F, e não favorecer a leitura em F...  Corrigi esta parte da resposta... valeu.

Answer (score -2):

O `<strong>` é uma tag semântica do HTML que ser para dar mais importância/urgência/seriedade a determinado texto. Você apenas deve realmente usa-lo caso aquele texto que você está marcando for realmente importante para o usuário da página. Se você estiver usando `<strong>` só por que você está achando que seria legal usar ele ou porque você quer marcar algumas palavras só pra dizer que marcou... Não fica legal. E isso realmente parece que é o que você está fazendo ao dar importância muitas vezes a palavra div sem necessidade.

Caso você queira marcar palavras-chaves no documento, utilize a tag `<b>`, que serve para propósitos materiais, sem necessariamente oferecer uma importância considerável para o texto, o que é ideial para marcar as palavras-chaves.

```
<p>
O HTML é uma <b>linguagem de marcação</b> muito antiga e usada para <b>desenvolvimento web</b>. Ela foi inventada por <b>Tim Bernes-Lee</b>.
</p>
```

O `<strong>` também define hierarquias de informações, tipo quando você quer destacar uma determinada palavra de um título:

```
<h1>
    O Brasil <strong>superou a crise</strong>
</h1>
```

Esse é um caso de uso válido.